# Unit test fails on PITclipse but succeeds in JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, pitest

In PITclipse, I am receiving this error after the test:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.help.PitHelpError: All tests did not pass without mutation when calculating line coverage. Mutation testing requires a green suite.
See http://pitest.org for more details.
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.verifyBuildSuitableForMutationTesting(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:104)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:89)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:46)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.runReport(MutationCoverage.java:118)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:101)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:43)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.runReport(MutationCoverageReport.java:71)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:43)
    at org.pitest.pitclipse.pitrunner.PitRunner.runPIT(PitRunner.java:49)
    at org.pitest.pitclipse.pitrunner.PitRunner.main(PitRunner.java:28)
```

It says the tests did not past, however JUnit has no errors or failures.

Not sure what the cause of this is so if you need any further information, please ask.

Comment: Does it point to any line of code?

Comment: can you isolate as to which test causes this? What kind of tests you have? with standard/maven pitest, you can enable `verbose` option that will tell exactly which test failed to run. Not sure if that's possible with pitclipse, but check. Also, are you using latest version of Pitclipse?

Comment: @eis For some reason pit says I have a java.outofmemory error on a test class. Im running PITclipse 1.0.0

Comment: @codingbash  I guess you need to either optimize the test or allocate more memory

Comment: afaik current version is `1.1.2.201502230916`

Comment: For anyone viewing the question now, from my memory the problem results in a configuration issue in Pitclipse and/or JUnit dependency. Also make sure they are using the same JDK/JRE version.